# Move multiple strips in the Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, keyframes, selection-tools, shortcut

I'd read elsewhere that in the dope sheet I could type <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, and then <kbd>G</kbd> and a *Number*. But that doesn't seem to do anything. Is there a *Insert frames* command, or something like that? Can I select all my video strips and move them 'jointly' to the right (to a higher frame) without screwing up the keyframe transitions?

I want to add a title sequence to a video compilation I've made. Sadly, I started my videos at Frame 1. I feel like this should be simple, but I can't figure it out. I'm a Blender noob.

I'm running Linux 15.10 and Blender 2.76b.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you successfully make a selection of all strips?  When you press [a] to select all or deselect all,    do you see the visual cues such a white highlights appear around the strips appear in the interface ... or do  you see nothing?

Comment: Most actions in Blender are Context oriented. So you need your mouse to hover over the area you want to perform an action in. And finally you need some keyframes before you see anything in the Dope Sheet editor. So insert some with hovering over an animatable element and pressing I.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I was pressing "A" in the dope sheet view, and yes, all the elements in the dope sheet view became highlighted. Perhaps I was using the keyboard wrong, but following the "A" with "G" and then typing numbers wasn't making a change. I followed the instructions in the sequencer window (in the comments below), and the strips and keyframes moved properly.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Samoth Thanks for the context tip. I've been learning that slowly (thick head, perhaps). I did have the keyframes added, and they moved properly with the A-G-drag technique described in the comments below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most keyboard shortcuts work on different windows in blender.

<kbd>A</kbd> will allow you to select all.

Then if you press <kbd>G</kbd> and drag, you can move all the video strips together with the mouse:

[image]

To move the strips a specific number of frames use <kbd>G</kbd>, then type number of frames you want to move and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Postitive numbers will move the strips to the right, negative numbers will move them to the left.

[image]

The transitions and keyframes will follow the video strips automatically.

[image]

Comment: Wow. I had hoped for a workable answer, but you created a simple, Rolls Royce-quality answer with a video tutorial!  You're amazing!!!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there an easy way to select everything after a certain point? I find myself often needing to insert a small adjustment in the center of a complicated mix. Currently I zoom out and box select but this is a pain.

Comment: @JamesWatkins new questions should be asked in a new post.

Comment: @JamesWatkins, for this use Select -> All strips to the Right (Left)

Answer (score 1):

Consider keeping your mouse in the VSE window area when you press <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>, *Number*.

When you press <kbd>A</kbd> you should see all strips toggle between select or deselect state. Press <kbd>A</kbd> such that all strips are selected.

Comment: Sure? Just out of interest: Why you don't want to have key markup?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + *mouse click* adds to the selection.
Active item: white border.
Selected item: darkened.

[image: Shift+Click adds to selection. Active: white border. Selected: darkened.]

(https://i.imgur.com/r5kvNCD / https://gph.is/2At0Rmp)

<kbd>G</kbd> moves selection.

---

Also: <kbd>B</kbd> starts border/box select mode.

Manual:

- https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/selecting.html
- https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/editing.html